# Detecting SVG-EDIT window closing

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-edit

Is it possible to intercept the closing of the SVG-EDIT window?

We need to do some file cleanup upon closing the window (such as removing the temporary background image we supplied to SVG-EDIT).

Thanks!

Comment: By adding an onbeforeunload handler or an onunload handler perhaps?

Comment: I found a working solution and posted it here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021752/embedding-svg-edit-as-a-inline-editor/31697331#31697331