# Embedding SVG edit as a inline editor

Tags: edit, svg-edit

How can this be accomplished in a HTML page:
Click on the SVG image will open SVG editor in another window. On closing the window (after Y/N prompt) the svg code in the opener window will be updated.

Comment: I have no clue of how to send the SVG back and forth to an editor window. 
I was trying something along the lines: h=window.open....
is there an example. So far I manually copy the SVG html  but that is rather clumsy

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution: having opened the editor with

```
hWinEdit=window.open('svg-edit-2.7/svg-editor.html','SVG-edit');
```

I then add the onbeforeunload event:

```
hWinEdit.onbeforeunload=function(){hWinEdit.opener.svgClose();};
```

where `svgClose` is my function getting the SVG HTML string:

```
s=hWinEdit.svgCanvas.getSvgString();
```

Anyway I think I have to abandon SVG-Edit as there are too many critical bugs for my purpose. (Connectors not working, hangups etc)